# Drawing in JPanel disappears when scrolling or ressizing the main frame

Tags: java

I draw many shapes in panel and it works, but **when I scroll the panel or when I resize the frame the drawings disappears**.

I looked  at other questions on this topic, but did not find a solution to the problem.

The screenshots:

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3]

The code:

```
public class ZoomPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ZoomPane();
    }

    public ZoomPane() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                .  . .
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private float scale = 1;

        public TestPane() {
            addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                    double delta = 0.05f * e.getPreciseWheelRotation();
                    scale += delta;
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 200);
            size.width = Math.round(size.width * scale);
            size.height = Math.round(size.height * scale);
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(scale, scale);
            g2d.setTransform(at);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);


            gr.draw(new Line2D.Double((int)this.getWidth() / 2, 0, (int)this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight())); 
            gr.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, (int)this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth(), (int)this.getHeight() / 2));


            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**How can I fix this bug?**

Comment: please include all the code necessary to reproduce your error

Comment: Upon scrolling and resizing, the JPanel must redraw. If your `paintComponent` method changes what it draws from draw call to draw call(in other words, there's animation), then you are going to have issues with stuff not drawing exactly how you expect.

Comment: @elbraulio, this is all code. 
where is the comment (//Drawing) such a code:
`gr.draw(new Line2D.Double((int)this.getWidth() / 2, 0, (int)this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight()));
         gr.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, (int)this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth(), (int)this.getHeight() / 2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clobbering the Graphics2D transform put in place by Swing.  JScrollPane relies on it.

Instead of *replacing* the transform, you need to *append* to it.  Replace this:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.setTransform(at);
```

with this:

```
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.transform(at);
```

The `setTransform` replaces the transform;  the `transform` method appends to it.

A cleaner solution is to replace all three lines with this:

```
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
```